# Row selection missing while scrolling the kendo grid with local vritual loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am working on a web application using kendo.I have kendo grid with local vritual loading.But my row selection islosing while scrolling the grid.I know virtual scrolling not supporting this.But I did like the below code using time out.

```
setTimeout(function () {
                        var firstRow = $(grid.table).find(tr).first()[0];
                        grid.select(firstRow);
                    }, 0.5);
```

Is there any perfect way to identify virtual data complete OR to keep the row selection?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event RequestStart of the datasource to backup your selection and then restore it during DataBound Event of the grid.